# reauthenticating a user logs him out

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

This is the code to reauthenticate a user before a firebase auth deletion.

```
 final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

 AuthCredential cred = EmailAuthProvider.credential(
    email: email,
    password: password,
 );
 UserCredential userCredential =
      await user.reauthenticateWithCredential(cred);
 
 // await userCredential.user?.delete(); commented out to test the reauthentication exceptions
```

When I test this with the correct email, and a wrong password I get an error and the app is fine.

But when I test it with a wrong email, when I press the button again, the app crashes due the current user being null.

When I restart the app, I go back to the login page. So it logs out the current user. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signing in with a different email address means that you're signing in with a different account. Apparently that signs out the current account, even if the new sign-in fails.

If you don't want to sign the current user out, consider [using a separate `FirebaseApp` object for each user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application). There is no code-sample there, but you should be able to get it to work based on the other languages and the [reference docs for Flutter](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/firebase_auth-library.html).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I definitely do not want to go through that hassle, if I can't learn from a code sample. I'm going to autofill the email address textfield and make it disabled to prevent the user from changing the email. Thus, only requesting the password. Thanks again. Much appreciated Frank.